# Adding Characters into Struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I am trying to read characters into a linked list (I made this simple test code just to try to read in the characters) for some reason I cannot get it to read in a character value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[50];
    struct node *next;
}*head;

void add(char AddName);

int main()
{

    head = NULL;
    char TempName[50];

    printf("What Name");
         scanf(" %s", TempName);

    add(TempName);

    printf("%s",head->name);


    return 0;
 }


void add(char AddName)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(temp->name,AddName);
    head = temp;
    head->next = NULL;
}
```

I understand this is not how a linked list works I just made this to try to get to be able to run a single character name into the struct and print it back out. (I should be able to enter in the name Bob and it prints bob)

Comment: The compiler should have shouted warnings at you about the code. *Read the warnings*, they are often just as important as errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your function parameter definition is wrong. Try this:

```
void add(char *AddName)
{
....
}
```